# Unnecessary Span Tags wrapping with the P tag in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using the below code in the editor mode of CKEditor:

```
<span class="note"><b>Note:</b> anything1 <br>
<p class="code">anything2  </p>
</span>
```

I have seen the preview in the CKEditor and again check the editor mode , my code has been changed now. Now its look like as below:

```
<span class="note"><b>Note:</b> anything1  </span>
<p class="code"><span class="note"> anything2 </span></p>
<span class="note"> </span>
```

There is an extra unnecessary span tag after p tag. Please suggest how to remove it.

Comment: Do you have some sort of loop running to print this code?

Comment: No I just added above code in the editor mode. And its just adding the unnecessary <span class="note"> after the P tag.

Comment: <p class="code">anything2  </p> has converted to <p class="code"><span class="note"> anything2 </span></p>.
"code" and "note" are the custom css classes.

Comment: @shan you can not do that, it may be the behavior of CKEditor to wrap up text in span tag.

Comment: Yes I want to stop this default behavior of CKEditor. This is adding unnecessary class which is not required.